# При клике на элемент меню, меню скрывается

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть выпадающее меню на jQuery. Хочу сделать так, чтоб при клике на ссылку меню все таки закрывалось, а не оставалось открытым. Как быть? 
Вот попытки:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.humb').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass('active');
});

if ( $('.nav').hasClass('active')) {
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.nav').removeClass('active');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.humb').click(function(){
        $('.nav').toggleClass('active'); 
       });
     $('ul li a').click(function() {
        if ( $('.nav').hasClass('active')) {
         $('.nav').removeClass('active');
        }
     }) 
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо большое